# Parsing date 41777 start date 01/01/1998?

Tags: c++

I'm trying to parse a 16 bits date to an actual date dd/mm/yyyy.
I'm getting  int =41777. how to translate that to a date?.
the data is from a load cell TEDs and according to IEEE 1451.4 it's supposed to be days since 01/01/1998.
Can you please help parse the number 41777 to date?

Answer (score 1):

There is no parsing involved. You need to create a date in C++ initialized to 1/1/1980 then add 41777 days to it.
See http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_39_0/doc/html/date_time/examples.html#date%5Ftime.examples.time%5Fmath for how to do this with the Boost library. There are also other C++ libraries to handle date and time.

Comment: Hi Tarik,Thank you for the response. I'm still confused how to do it!!. The number 41777 supposed to correspond to 01/01/2009.

Comment: ooops sorry the date is 01/05/2009.

Comment: @starwick Do you use a specific date/time library?

Comment: Salam : Like I said before this is data from a load cell I'm just reading  2 bytes(16bits), what read is an int=41777 it's supposed to equal to 01/05/2009 as a date. According to the specs that's a date that is supposed to be days since 01/01/1998.

Comment: I was able to parse all the TEDs data it's all in the IEEE1451.4 and IEEE754 except for the date format!!!!!!!!!!!!

Answer (score -1):

If you do not want to use a library you can use the algorithm presented [here](https://howardhinnant.github.io/date_algorithms.html#civil_from_days/%22here%22). Since civil_from_days assumes that the given value is days since 1st jan 1970 you always have add 10227 days (1st jan 1998 - 1st jan 1970) to your value.